# Are these two ways of calling a class in Python equivalent?

Tags: python, class

I have the following class setup:

```
SUITS = ["D", "C", "H", "S"]

class CardDeck:
    #creates a pack of cards (no jokers)
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for s in SUITS:
            for x in range(1, 14):
                self.cards.append(s + str(x))

    #sets as as high if True
    def aceHigh(self, bool):
        if bool == True:
            for s in SUITS:
                self.cards.remove(s + "1")
                self.cards.insert(12, s + "14")
        elif bool == False:
            print('Ace not high')
```

When I then do the following I seem to get the same results. Are these two ways of calling/accessing methods/classes always equivalent? Is one better than the other for any reason (in particular am I right in thinking the first approach recursive)? Thanks

```
x = CardDeck()
y = CardDeck()

CardDeck.aceHigh(x, True)

y.aceHigh(True)

print(x.cards)
print(y.cards)
```

Comment: No, the first approach has nothing to do with recursion. The second approach is preferable, since it's immediately obvious which `CardDeck` instance you are actually dealing with.

Comment: No, don't do this: `CardDeck.aceHigh(x, True)`. This has nothing to do with recursion.